# With jekyll / liquid how to get all keys of a yml hash

Tags: collections, yaml, jekyll, liquid

I have this yaml

```
param1:
  key1: value1
  key2: value2

param2:
  key1: value1
  key2: value2

param3:
  key1: value1
  key2: value2
```

how can I get all the keys with a liquid?

The expected result would be

```
param1,param2,param3
```

Any idea?

- very ugly solution: {% for %} on the collection and concat the keys...
- acceptable alternative solution: create a liquid filter "keys" ... sound too big that it does not actually exists ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I implemented a small filter to get the hash keys :

https://github.com/MichaelCurrin/jekyll-keys-filter

Just have to write something like:

```
{{ hash | keys }}
```

Comment: Repo doesn't exist. Suggest to either update the answer or delete it.

Comment: The repro maybe moved [GitHub](https://github.com/MichaelCurrin/jekyll-keys-filter)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you an other format for your yml file

```
- id: param1
  key1: value1
  key2: value2

- id: param2
  key1: value1
  key2: value2

- id: param3
  key1: value1
  key2: value2
```

Then you could use `{{ site.data.file | map: "id" | join: "," }}`

Comment: That solve my problem, but you changed the iniital problem too ^^

Answer (score 0):

I used your "ugly solution" of looping through the collection elements:

```
{%  for hash in site.data.file -%}
    {{hash[0]}},
{%- endfor %}
```

If you want to get rid of the trailing ',':

```
{%  for hash in site.data.file limit: 1 -%}
    {{hash[0]}}
{%- endfor %}
{%- for hash in site.data.file offset: 1 -%}
    ,{{hash[0]}}
{%- endfor %}
```